# How to prevent File Modification in C++

Tags: windows, c++, patching, binary-editing

so i want to protect my software against reverse-engineering and i want to add checksum verification to prevent patching the binary but the problem that if i added a checksum verification the binary changes, how's the proper way to do it?

Comment: Your effort to prevent patching by adding / verification of checksum is a useless waste of your time. I'm sorry, it's a naive approach.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent patching. There are ways to make reverse engineering harder, but the checksum approach is not the best way. There are way more advanced methods, that cannot be compared to a custom-made antitampering routine.

Even those advanced  methods become eventually studied and cracked.

Either you have to rely on commercial protections (maybe hardware-dependent like dongles), or you have to give a great effort on designing your protection scheme, but have in mind that if someone skilled enough is determined to crack your app, it will happen.

Comment: i know that it will gonna be cracked anyway using: Loader (editing in memory), Removing Protection Code, etc.... , and i don't want to depend on other people software to protect my software i want to protect it myself, and the goal is not to prevent it anyway cause i know it's impossible i want to make it harder, can you send a website or something that can help?

Comment: @Ahmed, *"... i know it's impossible i want to make it harder ..."* - harder for whom??? Any reverse engineer will break your amateur protector within seconds or few minutes, while other people may barely change your software beyond changing some text strings.

Comment: @MarianD what do you mean with "Any reverse engineer will break your amateur (((protector)))" do you even know what's going on? i literally said "i want to protect my software against reverse-engineering" not making a protector, please next time when you read someone question PLEASE READ THE WHOLE QUESTION FOR THE SAKE OF GOD, and if you can't help or seeing that my question are stupid then simply don't answer it, not trying to get smarter on somebody because he just started learning something.

Comment: @Ahmed, excuse me, please, I didn't want to offend you, believe me. I wanted to help you not waste your time for something which is useless. But if it is only for your learning and understanding, it's OK.

Comment: @MarianD that's not the way you help somebody, you tell him what's better to do and if you really wanted to help him then give him a website or a sample code that can help him to go to the right direction, not saying "Any reverse engineer will break your amateur protector within seconds or few minute", but yeah it's fine.

Comment: @Ahmed, you're right, but for some readers my comment may be helpful. I'm sorry  that for you it turns out as a useless because of your goal not to examine reverse engineers but only to make progress in your learning. I wish you a great success, and maybe in the future I will satisfy you with a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a packer. Packers such as [VMProtect](https://vmpsoft.com/), have something called virtualization engine - where code is encrypted, never actually decrypted, because it runs through a virtual CPU. This is probably the toughest thing to crack in any client-sided protection possible.

There are a few other packers out that have this feature as well. If you really want top notch client-sided security, look out for this feature (of course include others like anti-debugging on so on.). You will want to keep it up to date, because there are usually scripts made to unpack/decrypt these protection tools. It will probably cost a bomb though.

Without deep knowledge and understanding, it is actually not that easy to crack them. This alone would defeat the vast majority that have malicious intent.

Of course, you would know by now - that security that relies on client-sided security alone is never fully secured. But you can certainly make it hard to crack.

Comment: actually i want to do that myself i don't want to depend on other people software to protect mine (because i'm learning from it anyways) plus there's a scripts that devirtualize VMProtect.

Comment: @Ahmedminegames indeed there are scripts, but it is unlikely that they would work on the latest version - because there are usually updates to the virtualization engine that breaks the script. or at least there should be an update like this every X release/version of the packer. If you want to learn it yourself, you can search google on how to make your own PE file packer - you will need to study the PE file format, and how windows runs and interact with exe/dll files under the hood. That said, your protection will likely be crack-able even by amateurs.

Comment: In your original post, you mentioned checksum verification - checksum verification alone without other forms of protection makes the checksum verification nothing more than an if-else statement. A malicious author would just need to patch this if-else statement. Your goal would then be to make it hard for them to patch it. For example, you could embed your entire file into another file - so a file in a file. Encrypt the original file, and only decrypt and load it at runtime. Perform a checksum verification on both ends - before decrypting the file, and after the file is decrypted at runtime.

Comment: Many other ways to go about protecting a file. Google will be your best source of answer.

Comment: no i have another protections such as anti-debugging, anti-hooking, etc......, and there's nobody talked about preventing patching the binary / prevent file modifying in C++, "you could embed your entire file into another file - so a file in a file. Encrypt the original file, and only decrypt and load it at runtime."  so i just encrypt my program with something simple like XOR (many layers) and then decrypt it in runtime? what is the best way to do it though, do i just embed the program inside the resources? and i need to prevent dumping right?

Comment: XOR with many layers may not give you the encryption you intend for it to have. Encryption doesn't get stronger by stacking XOR outputs. Cryptography is quite a complex study, so you are probably better off just using something like AES. You don't have to embed it inside resources where it is pretty obvious there is a file - because the resource section will become huge in size. You can extend use any section of the program (even .code if you extend it). You can even split up the file into e.g 3 different parts across the program.

Comment: Being creative in how you apply these protection techniques will give you far better results for sure. You would only need to apply anti-dumping techniques after the protected file is decrypted and loaded at runtime. Dumping before the protected file runs is pointless - because the file is still encrypted.

Comment: Take a look at the features offered by commercial packers like VMProtect and Themida. You can copy from them and be creative - mix it up and apply other techniques on top of them.

Comment: Judging from how badly you want to protect your file - you may want to write your own kernel driver. With a driver, there will be more ways to protect your file. You would have to get the driver signed though.

Comment: ... which would require having a company, because individuals will be unable to procure an EV certificate. And standard class 3 certificates won't do on standard customer systems.